# Python ImportError while module is installed [Ubuntu]

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'd like to make a switch from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu) writing my python programs but I just can't get things to work. Here's the problem: I can see that there are quite the number of modules pre-installed (like numpy, pandas, matplotlib, etc.) in Ubuntu. They sit nicely in the /host/Python27/Lib/site-packages directory. But when I write a test python script and try to execute it, it gives me an ImportError whenever I try to import a module (for instance `import numpy as np` gives me `ImportError: No module named numpy`). When I type `which python` in the commandline I get the `/usr/bin/python` path. I think I might need to change things related to the python path, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following command in your terminal to see what folders are in your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
python -c "import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
```

I'm guessing `/host/Python27/Lib/site-packages` wont be in there (it doesn't sound like a normal python path. How did you install these packages?).

If you want to add folders to your `PYTHONPATH` then use the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/host/Python27/Lib/site-packages
```

Personally here are some recommendations for developing with Python:

1. Use [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It is a very powerful tool that creates sandboxed python environments so you can install modules and keep them separate from the main interpreter.
2. Use [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) - When you've created a `virtualenv`, and activated it you can use `pip install` to install packages for you. e.g. `pip install numpy` will install numpy into your virtual environment and will be accessible from only this virtualenv. This means you can also install different versions for testing etc. Very powerful. I would recommend using `pip` to install your python packages over using ubuntu `apt-get install` as you are more likely to get the newer versions of modules (`apt-get` relies on someone packaging the latest versions of your python libraries and may not be available for as many libraries as `pip`).
3. When writing python scripts that you will make executable (`chmod +x my_python_script.py`) make sure you put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top as this will pick up the python interpreter in your virtual environment. If you don't (and put `#!/usr/bin/python`) then running `./my_python_script.py` will always use the system python interpreter.

Comment: I guess the packages got installed by Ubuntu, since I did not install any python packages myself after this fresh installation of Ubuntu. I have tried adding the `/host/...` path to the PYTHONPATH, but then it still can't find all sorts of dependencies. I will try to use `virtualenv` instead and see if it works. Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 2):

`/host/Python27/Lib/site-packages` is not a default python directory on linux installations as far as I am aware.

The normal python installation (and python packages) should be found under `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` depending on your processor architecture.

If you want to check where python is searching in addition to these directories you can use a terminal with the following command:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

If the `/host/Python27/Lib/site-packages` path is not listed, attempt to use the following command and try it again:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:host/Python27/Lib/site-packages
```

If this should work and you do not want to write this in a terminal every time you want to use these packages, simply put it into a file called `.bashrc` in your `home` folder (normally `/home/<username>`).

Answer (score 0):

When installing other python libraries, specify the pip version you want to install it to, if it's python2 you use, then enter this syntax:

```
pip2 install <package>
```

For python3

```
pip3 install <package>
```